# There is a difference between the image output on the program screen and the final rendered image

Tags: rendering

When rendering in Blender,
When comparing the image output on the program screen with the final rendered image, the color saturation of the rendered image is too high

I'm wondering what modifications can I make to reduce the difference between the expected render image and the final image.

[image]

[This file link](http://sendanywhe.re/8ZOWZC3D) was posted on January 11th and is valid until January 13th.

Comment: though there are ways to go about doing it, i would usually use a color correction node in the compositor

Comment: it's generally the opposite, the render is duller, could you please share a part of your file (just the walls and lights for example)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: My guess is you have a blue light hidden / disabled in viewport, but not disabled in render.

Comment: compositing maybe?

Comment: if u share your blend file, we can check it out, else we can just guess

Comment: I checked it now. i have uploaded the file to thank you for your request. You can go to the link and download it. If you have any problems, please let me know. I can also send you by email.

Comment: Hi,I just rendered the image right now and both the viewport preview and the render look the same. What's the problem, then?

Comment: I also just accidentally saved and reopened the file and was puzzled.

Randomly change the color of the cube wall object at random (eg pink), save it again, close it, and open it again, and it is saved as a bright blue color.

It seems that the material color initially set (probably bright sky blue at that time) does not change.

Comment: I solved it! The problem seems to be that the object (cube wall) has an error with the sky blue material. If you release the face connected to the material, delete it, and set it to a new material, it will render normally. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: The object has no problem with the material - the material itself has the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your material has a keyframe at frame 1 on the RGB color, that's why it always gets reset. Even if you change values and they are displayed correctly in the viewport without setting a new keyframe, Blender resets the values to the keyframed ones before render and upon re-opening of course.

[image: color keyframe]